# Mask two columns with a list of list ( Pandas df)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list containing lists of exactly two elements.

I want to filter my DataFrame to rows where `[column_a, column_b]` is in the list of lists.

Example:

Input:

```
l = [ [0,1], [1,2] ]
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_a' : [0, 1, 2], 'column_b' : [1, 3, 0]})

   column_a  column_b
0         0         1
1         1         3
2         2         0
```

Expected output:

```
   column_a  column_b
0         0         1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a df from the list and merge:

```
df.merge(pd.DataFrame(l,columns=df.columns))
```

---

```
   column_a  column_b
0         0         1
```

Answer (score 2):

Some time for loop is not bad at all

```
df[[x in l for x in df.values.tolist()]]
Out[135]: 
   column_a  column_b
0         0         1
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution

```
l = [[0, 1], [1, 2]]
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_a': [0, 1, 2], 'column_b': [1, 3, 0]})
for elem in l:
    df.loc[(df['column_a'] == elem[0]) & (df['column_b'] == elem[1]), 'Result'] = 1
df = df[df['Result'] == 1].drop(['Result'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   column_a  column_b
0         0         1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```py
l = [ [0,1], [1,2] ]
l=[tuple(el) for el in l]
#it has to be in tuple format

df.loc[df[['column_a', 'column_b']].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(l)]
```

Output:

```py
   column_a  column_b
0         0         1
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it by adding a column. Maybe not the simplest way but it works:

```
df['c'] = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(df['column_a'], df['column_b'])]

df[[x in l for x in df['c']]]
```

---

Output:

```
   column_a  column_b       c
0         0         1  [0, 1]
```